# Drop row if string is not equal to value - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping to drop rows if the string after a specific value is not equal to a list of value. Specifically, if the subsequent row after either `'Up' or 'Left'` is not followed by `'Right'` or `'Down'` then I'm aiming to drop those rows.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Label' : ['A','B','A','B','B','B','A','B','B','A','A','A'],   
    'Item' : ['X','Left','X','Left','Down','Right','Up','Y','Right','Y','Right','Up'],      
    })

df1 = df[~(df['Item'].isin(['Up','Left']).shift(1)) & (df['Item'].isin(['Right','Down']))]

   Label   Item
0      A      X
1      B   Left
2      A      X # Drop. Not Right/Down
3      B   Left
4      B   Down # Keep. Right/Down
5      B  Right
6      A     Up
7      B      Y # Drop. Not Right/Down
8      B  Right
9      A      Y
10     A  Right
11     A     Up
```

intended output:

```
   Label   Item
0      A      X
1      B   Left
3      B   Left
4      B   Down
5      B  Right
6      A     Up
8      B  Right
9      A      Y
10     A  Right
11     A     Up
```

Comment: Can you please also print out the original dataframe for our clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the mask. It'll solve your problem now -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Label' : ['A','B','A','B','B','B','A','B','B','A','A','A'],   
    'Item' : ['X','Left','X','Left','Down','Right','Up','Y','Right','Y','Right','Up'],      
    })

mask = (~(df['Item'].isin(['Up','Left']) & (~df['Item'].shift(-1).isin(['Right','Down',np.NAN]))))
df1 = df[mask.shift(1,fill_value=True)]
print(df1)
```

**output -**

```
   Label   Item
0      A      X
1      B   Left
3      B   Left
4      B   Down
5      B  Right
6      A     Up
8      B  Right
9      A      Y
10     A  Right
11     A     Up
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine, it's just missing the `not` in the second condition

> if the subsequent row after either 'Up' or 'Left' is **not** followed by
> 'Right' or 'Down' then I'm aiming to drop those rows.

So it should be like this:

```
df1 = df[~(((df['Item'].isin(['Up','Left']).shift(1)) & ~(df['Item'].isin(['Right','Down']))))]
```

Answer (score 2):

First create a `left up` mask determining the index of `Left` and `Up` value in column `Item`.

Then shift the `left up` mask to get `right down` mask determining the location we want to check.

```py
lu_mask = (df['Item'] == 'Left') | (df['Item'] == 'Up')
rd_mask = lu_mask.shift(1).fillna(False)
```

Moreover, use `right down` mask to check if the row is `Right` or `Down`.

```py
index_to_drop = ((df.loc[rd_mask, 'Item'] != 'Right') & (df.loc[rd_mask, 'Item'] != 'Down')).loc[lambda s: s == True]
```

At last, drop the row.

```py
df_ = df[~df.index.isin(index_to_drop.index)]
```

```
# print(df_)

   Label   Item
0      A      X
1      B   Left
3      B   Left
4      B   Down
5      B  Right
6      A     Up
8      B  Right
9      A      Y
10     A  Right
11     A     Up
```

Answer (score 1):

I think here is simplier solution like accepted answer:

Your solution change by chain by `|` for bitwise `OR` and first shifting values and then compare:

```
df2 = df[df['Item'].isin(['Right','Down']) | ~df['Item'].shift().isin(['Up','Left'])]
print (df2)
   Label   Item
0      A      X
1      B   Left
3      B   Left
4      B   Down
5      B  Right
6      A     Up
8      B  Right
9      A      Y
10     A  Right
11     A     Up
```